# Multiple Integral Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, integral-equations

$$f(x) = 2a \int_{0}^{x}{f(t)\;dt} - \left(\frac{b^2}{2}\right)\int_{0}^{1}{|x-t|f(t)\;dt}$$
where $0<a<b$

My task is to solve for $f(x)$.  I'm having difficulty solving this integral equation.  What makes it really hard is the variable upper bound in the first integral, therefore implies that this is a Volterra integral equation.  However this is a double integral equation.  The second equation is a Fredholm integral equation.  That's where I'm stuck.  I've tried hitting it from different angles, but only to be in vain.

Answer (score 4):

Split the second integral from $0$ to $x$ and from $x$ to $1$.
$$f(x)=2a\int_0^xf(t)~dt-\dfrac{b^2}2\int_0^x(x-t)f(t)~dt+\dfrac{b^2}2\int_x^1(x-t)f(t)~dt$$
Now from fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$f'(x)=2af(x)-\dfrac{b^2}2\int_0^xf(t)~dt+\dfrac{b^2}2\int_x^1f(t)~dt$$
Differentiate it again to get
$$f''(x) = 2af'(x) - b^2 f(x)$$
$$f(x)=C_1e^{ax}\sin\sqrt{b^2-a^2}x+C_2e^{ax}\cos\sqrt{b^2-a^2}x$$
Now substitute the solution back to the integral equation to determine $C_1$ and $C_2$ , i.e. to determine $C_1$ and $C_2$ from the following identity
$$C_1e^{ax}\sin\sqrt{b^2-a^2}x+C_2e^{ax}\cos\sqrt{b^2-a^2}x\equiv2a\int_0^x(C_1e^{at}\sin\sqrt{b^2-a^2}t+C_2e^{at}\cos\sqrt{b^2-a^2}t)~dt-\dfrac{b^2}2\int_0^1|x-t|(C_1e^{at}\sin\sqrt{b^2-a^2}t+C_2e^{at}\cos\sqrt{b^2-a^2}t)~dt$$

Comment: I'm confused. How do you get rid of the absolute value in the integral? And is the $\color{red}+$ bellow correct? $$f(x) = 2 a \int_0^x f(t) dt - \dfrac{b^2}2 \int_0^x (x-t) f(t) dt \color{red}+ \dfrac{b^2}2 \int_x^1 (x-t) f(t) dt$$

Comment: @GitGud $\vert x-t \vert = x-t$, when $x\geq t$ and $\vert x- t \vert = -(x-t)$, when $x \leq t$ and yes it is $\color{red}+$. The minus combines with another minus to give us $\color{red}+$.

Comment: Why is it that, for instance in $\int \limits _0^x$, $x\ge t$?

Comment: @GitGud In the integral, $\int_0^x \vert x-t \vert f(t) dt$, we have $t$ goes from $0$ to $x$. Hence, $x-t > 0$. Hence, $\vert x-t \vert = x-t$.

Comment: I was blind, thanks.